# Submeter formulário com <a href=""> ao invés de <input="submit">

Tags: html, css

Foi-me dado um layout de um formulário:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="mail_form">
   <div id="newsletter"> 
      <input type="text" name="email_newsletter" />
      <div class="newslink">
         <input type="hidden" name="submit_newsletter" />
         <a href="">ENVIAR</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Como é que posso fazer para que, ao clicar em "ENVIAR", o formulário seja submetido à partir do `<a href="">`?

Eu sei que há outras formas de se enviar um formulário, mas neste caso, gostaria de enviar assim.

Comment: Para isso você terá que fazer em javascript ou jquery.. tudo bem pra você se eu der a resposta em javascript?

Comment: @pc_oc Acredito que o código que o Bacco meteu é a melhor solução da sua pergunta..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Desta forma, somente com javascript.

O método correto é usar um botão do tipo `<input type="submit">`, um `<button type="submit">` ou uma `<input type="image">`, estes dois últimos tem efeito parecido com submit, sendo que o `button` permite outros elementos aninhados (imagens inclusive), e o segundo permite o envio ao se clicar em uma imagem específica (enviando junto as coordenadas clicadas).

Se mesmo assim quiser um `<a>`, segue o código. Não recomendo, pois afeta a acessibilidade do formulário.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="mail_form">
    <div id="newsletter"> 
        <input type="text" name="email_newsletter" />
        <div class="newslink">
            <input type="hidden" name="submit_newsletter" />
            <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('mail_form').submit();">ENVIAR</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> Lembre-se que hoje em dia, usando CSS, você consegue deixar o `submit` convencional com aparência igual a um link comum, com a vantagem de não "quebrar" a funcionalidade normal do `form`.

Ainda teria uma gambiarra que é usar um `<label for="botaodeenvio">` e esconder o botão original com posição, opacidade, etc, mas vai continuar não sendo um `<a>`. Melhor usar CSS e os métodos convencionais.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um código simplificado como este **javascript:x.submit()**

```
<a href='javascript:formName.submit()'>ENVIAR</a>
```

Onde formName corresponde ao name do formulário, exemplo:

```
<form name='pagamento' action=teste.html>
/*Conteúdo do formulário*/
</form>
```

E o link ficaria desta forma:

```html
<a href='javascript:pagamento.submit()' target='_blank'>ENVIAR</a>
<form name='pagamento' action='teste.html' >
<input value='10' name='valor' type='hidden'/>
</form>
```